# Error When Fitting Model in TensorFlow: logits and labels must have the same first dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, lstm

I am new to using TensorFlow, but I am trying to build an LSTM Model using tokenized strings as inputs.

```
# Define the model
def build_lstm_model():
    input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids')
    
    # BERT embedding layer
    bert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    bert_output = bert_model(input_ids)[1]  # using the pooled output

    # LSTM layer
    lstm_output = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)(tf.expand_dims(bert_output, axis=1))  # Expand the dimensions for LSTM

    # Output layer
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')(lstm_output)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_ids, outputs=output)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# Train the model
model = build_lstm_model()
#model.summary()

model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=3)
```

Trying to fit this model returns the error:

> logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [8,1] and labels shape [1024]

More notes:
'train_dataset' and 'val_dataset' are both TensorFlow datasets with shape=(None,128).

Here is the output of **model.summary()**:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_ids (InputLayer)      [(None, 128)]             0         
                                                                 
 tf_bert_model (TFBertModel  TFBaseModelOutputWithPo   109482240 
 )                           olingAndCrossAttentions             
                             (last_hidden_state=(Non             
                             e, 128, 768),                       
                              pooler_output=(None, 7             
                             68),                                
                              past_key_values=None,              
                             hidden_states=None, att             
                             entions=None, cross_att             
                             entions=None)                       
                                                                 
 tf.expand_dims (TFOpLambda  (None, 1, 768)            0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 64)                213248    
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 1)                 65        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 109695553 (418.46 MB)
Trainable params: 109695553 (418.46 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
```

I can't figure out how to get the dimensions to match so I can start training my model.

I tried the following solutions after reading other StackOverflow posts:

- Flattening the LSTM layer

```
lstm_output = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(lstm_output)
```

- Changing the output shape of the LSTM layer and Dense layer.
- Changing the loss function to 'categorical_crossentropy'.
- Changing the output layer activation to 'sigmoid'.

Comment: Whhat kind of dataset do you have? What expected shape have the labels?